# Multivalue input from chosen field giving patchy input strings from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, tool-validation, unicode, value-list

I made a small tool that can be run from a toolbox. It has a validation code to choose multiple values from a specified field from a specified feature layer. It looks quite ordinary:

[image: tool]

The validation code is:

```
def updateParameters(self):
   if self.params[1].altered:
      if self.params[1].value:
         values = set()
         inlayer = self.params[0].value.value
         fieldname = self.params[1].value.value

         cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(inlayer, None, None, infield)
         for row in cursor:
            values.add(row.getValue(infield))

         self.params[2].filter.list = sorted(values)
```

It gives me a nice multivalue list of values. But when I check some of them and run a simple script:

```
import arcpy
# Variables
inlayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
infield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
invalues = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.SetParameter(3, invalues)

selected_values = invalues.split(";")

for selected_value in selected_values:
    arcpy.AddWarning(selected_value)
```

then it returns some unicode strings with an apostrophe and some not. I found out that if there is a gap in the value, it returns an unicode string with an apostrophe. I don´t get it why? There´s a example output of the forementioned script:

[image]

In this tool window I can see that these apostrophes already figure as input values!

Why is that, and how do I avoid it?

These inputs with apostrophes troubles me further in my script because

```
if "withoutgap":
  # returns True but
if "with gap":
  # returns False because the unicode string has apostrophes
```

running on Windows 8.1, ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 Basic, Python 2.7

Comment: The main difference between the first two and the last two strings I can see is that the first two contain spaces. This is a wild guess but possibly the validator automatically wraps values with spaces in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a python expert so your code looks OK to me, I assume you are using a set() as a way of removing duplicates? If not and your dataset really does have only 4 rows in it then try using a list as all the examples in the ESRI help file uses lists...

Before you try that I would spoof up a second dataset which YOU have created and typed in those words that you want in the list. If that works as expected then it would suggest its a problem in the source dataset. Now this would not surprise me if the dataset has originated from say EXCEL which allows users to type and *copy* anything into it... So visually everything looks the same but behind the scenes it could have non-visible characters.

Comment: Yep, I´m using set() to remove duplicates. Each of these 4 values has many rows in a table so using a list is unfortunately not an option. The dataset I used for this example is created by me and those values are typed in - I wanted a clean dataset with "normal" values so I had typed them in manually. I know that spaces in these values force the validator to make a different output with apostrophes but I still don´t know why...

Comment: Hmm, OK you use GetParameterAsText() to create _invalues_, I wonder if you could try using GetParameter() and manipulate the returned object (I guess it will be a list object?). Just an idea?

Comment: Yes it works like a charm! I have always used GetParameterAsText() somehow automatically and GetParameter() never came to my mind. Great!