# Removing layer from TOC when it has space in name using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, python-toolbox, table-of-contents

I am trying to remove layers from the TOC using Python Toolbox. It works provided that the layer names have no spaces in their names. Tho whole script looks like:

```
class LayerprocessingRemoveUntickedLayers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Remove unticked layers"
        self.description = "Removes unticked layers."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param0 = parameter("toclayers", "Unticked layers", "GPString", "Optional", multiValue=True)

        params = [param0]
        return params

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        unticked_set = set()
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if not lyr.visible:
                unticked_set.add(lyr.longName)
            del lyr

        parameters[0].filter.list = sorted(list(unticked_set))
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        toclayers = parameters[0].valueAsText.split(";")  # ??? Here is my problem

        arcpy.AddMessage("\nTicked layers:")
        for t in toclayers:
            arcpy.AddMessage("... " + t)

        arcpy.AddMessage("\nRemoving chosen layers... ")
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if not lyr.visible and lyr.longName in toclayers:
                arcpy.AddMessage("... " + lyr.longName)
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
        return
```

**Step 1**: `updateParameters` function reads layers and gives me layers´ names.

[image: tool dialog]

**Step 2**: I tick layers I want to remove (it does no matter whether they are broken or not). There is no group layer.

**Step 3**: the script removes only those chosen layers that have no spaces in their names (in this case `PP_N_eroze_SUp` and `PP_N_eroze_SUt`). Obviously because layers with spaces in their names get quotes to their values.

[image: tool messaging]

Mr. Che commented that layers with spaces in their names get quotes when passed from tool dialog to script executing. And now I remember that I asked a question with the same problem some time ago as [Multivalue input from chosen field giving patchy input strings from ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119417)

The problem was in `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`, the solution was changing it to `arcpy.GetParameter(0)` and splitting its strings with ";" as Hornbydd suggested a long time ago.

It worked when the tool was within an ordinary toolbox. Now I have this tool in the Python toolbox but changing `parameters[0].valueAsText.split(";")` to `str(parameters[0].value).split(";")` is not working. How to get values (this is to say split values from `parameters[0]`) correctly?

Comment: Check your layer names and list of layers by printing them. Update your answer so we could see these printed values.

Comment: longName returns the full grouplayer path structure, are some of your layers group layers or sit within a group layer, this would explain why they are not removed  when you search in your toclayers list.

Comment: I updated the question and added tool´s messages. None of the layers are a group layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and checking errors I know now that ticked values are stored in a ValueTable object. So I created a list with values from this ValueTable and all of these values are now strings.

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    toclayers = parameters[0].value  # gives a ValueTable

    # Loop through the ValueTable and fill the list of values
    toclayers_list = []
    for i in xrange(0, toclayers.rowCount):
        toclayers_list.append(toclayers.getValue(i, 0))

    arcpy.AddMessage("\nTicked layers:")
    for t in toclayers_list:
        arcpy.AddMessage("... " + t)

    arcpy.AddMessage("\nRemoving chosen layers... ")
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
        if not lyr.visible and lyr.longName in toclayers_list:
            arcpy.AddMessage("... " + lyr.longName)
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

Tool messages:

[image]

Now it works.